# How do i create Image with text button

Tags: html, froala

I am using a froala custom editor and want to be able to create a custom menu item with a font and image vs one or the other. The editor allows one to specify and register a custom template. Below is a sample of templates.

```
FroalaEditor.ICON_TEMPLATES = {
  font_awesome: '<i class="fa fa-[NAME]" aria-hidden="true"></i>,',
  font_awesome_5: '<i class="fas fa-[FA5NAME]" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
  font_awesome_5s: '<i class="far fa-[FA5NAME]" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
  text: '<span style="text-align: center;">[NAME]</span>',
  image: '<img src=[SRC] alt=[ALT] />',
  svg: '<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">[PATH]</svg>'
}
```

so what i would like to do is create a template that combines the text and the image like

```
<span style="text-align: center;">[NAME]</span><img src=[SRC] alt=[ALT] />
```

but the above does not create the desired output as the image and the text are not centered in the middle. How can i get there to be the text first and then one space and after that the image centered in the middle just like the text ?